# Redirect After Registration on Specific Link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

I want to use registration_redirect to have users redirected to a certain page, only if they register using a certain link. Specifically, I want them to go from the registration link [here](https://casperfect.ca/practicetest) to registration, and then back to the link they came from - but only for this instance, not globally.

Is there an easy way to do this for this specific link? Perhaps a registration_redirect function that specifies for the page that the link to registration is on and then specifies the link to return to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this ode, dont forgot to change

ex: http://test.com/custom_page
custom_page => ( Change with your current registration page slug )

change this link 
'http://customlink.com/asdasda/' => (Change with where you want to redirect )

$registration_redirect = 'http://customlink.com/asdasda/'

```
add_filter( 'registration_redirect', 'my_redirect_home' );
function my_redirect_home( $registration_redirect ) {
    global $post;
    $post_slug=$post->post_name;
    if( 'custom_page' === $post_slug ){
        $registration_redirect = 'http://customlink.com/asdasda/';
    }
    return $registration_redirect;
}
```

Comment: whats the custom registration page url?

Comment: Would the slug simply be included with the $?

like this? https://pastebin.com/peGG1nHL

The link should redirect from the first page (/practicetest), register, and return to (/practicetest)

Comment: and where you want to redirect after registration?

Comment: in above code, change 
ex: http://test.com/custom_page
custom_page => ( with your current registration page slug )

also change this link 
'http://customlink.com/asdasda/'

Comment: updated above answer

Comment: One last question - there appears to be a syntax error on the 7th line. Could you help me fix that?

Comment: check code, it was this line 
 $registration_redirect = 'http://customlink.com/asdasda/';

Comment: Here's the code: https://pastebin.com/peGG1nHL

Still doesn't seem to be working. Am I missing something? It redirects to the standard My Account page.

Comment: where you adding code?

Comment: 10char functions.php